# Is there a proper way to use wildcards/regex in Jackcess?

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I have recently started using the Jackcess library in Java for dealing with MS Access databases. The library is pretty good but I have a question regarding searching rows.

Consider that I have "Jack loves apples" in a row of a column named X, what piece of code would I use to search for all the rows of X containing the word "apples"? I know this can be easily done using wildcards in SQL but since there is no way to use SQL queries in Jackcess, that's not a valid option.

I considered using UCanAccess but I have issues with the library, even if I use the "memory=false" option while loading the database, it still takes almost 1.4GB of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@centic's answer was accurate until jackcess version 3.5.0.  As of the 3.5.0 release, you can use the new [PatternColumnPredicate](https://jackcess.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/PatternColumnPredicate.html) class to do various wildcard/pattern/regex searches using Cursors.

Answer (score 0):

With Jackcess you need to iterate the rows and apply the filter yourself. As long as your filter is fairly static, this should be fairly easy to build.